# What is the Difference Between read() and recv() , and Between send() and write()?

Tags: c, sockets, unix, network-programming, posix

What is the difference between `read()` and `recv()`, and between `send()` and `write()` in socket programming in terms of performances, speed and other behaviors?

Comment: Think of write as implemented like this: `#define write(...) send(##__VA_ARGS__, 0)`.

Answer (score 172, accepted):

The difference is that `recv()`/`send()` work only on socket descriptors and let you specify certain options for the actual operation. Those functions are slightly more specialized (for instance, you can set a flag to ignore `SIGPIPE`, or to send out-of-band messages...).

Functions `read()`/`write()` are the *universal* file descriptor functions working on all descriptors.

Comment: This is incorrect, there's one other difference in case of datagrams of 0 length - If a zero-length datagram is pending, read(2) and recv() with  a  flags
       argument  of  zero  provide  different behavior.  In this circumstance,
       read(2) has no effect (the  datagram  remains  pending),  while  recv()
       consumes the pending datagram.

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal How would that provide _different behavior_? If there's a 0 byte datagram, both, `recv` and `read` will deliver no data to the caller but also no error. For the caller, the behavior is the same. The caller may not even know anything about datagrams (it may not know that this is a socket and not a file, it may not know that this is a datagram socket and not a stream socket). That the datagram stays pending is implicit knowledge about how IP stacks work in kernels and not visible to the caller. From caller perspective, they will still provide equal behavior.

Comment: @Mecki that's not implicit knowledge for everyone, take me for example :)

Comment: @Mecki if the datagram stays pending in only the `read` scenario, wouldn't that cause repeated `read`s to repeatedly "succeed" with zero-length reads (so, infinitely)?

Comment: @sehe A `read` of 0 bytes without error is documented as "end-of-stream". So yes, you can keep reading as long as you won't but the system already told you that you are at the end thus you cannot expect any more data to be read. For `recv` the same is documented for stream sockets (e.g. TCP). Datagram sockets (e.g. UDP) have no beginning and no end, so returning zero bytes has no specified meaning for them.

Comment: @Mecki what does a non-blocking successful read of 0 bytes indicate? Does the datagram still stay pending? Exactly that, and only that, is worrying me: the behaviour that a datagram can stay pending even if successfully read. I'm not sure whether the situation can arise, which is wy I'd like to keep it in mind.

Comment: @sehe If you are worried, why don't you use `recv`? The reason why `recv` and `send` where introduced in the first place was the fact that not all datagram concepts could be mapped to the world of streams. `read` and `write` treat everything as a stream of data, whether it is a pipe, a file, a device (e.g. a serial port) or a socket. Yet a socket is only a real stream if it uses TCP. If it uses UDP it's more like a block device. But if both sides use it like a stream, it will work like a stream and you cannot even send an empty UDP packet using `write` calls, so this situation won't arise.

Comment: @Mecki that's the approach I was gravitating to. It's just that lots of legacy code use the `read` style interface and I'd rather to be more sure that this is actually ok (with non-blocking reads). Thank you for your clarifying remarks. That's really helpful. I love when people take the time to share these bits of hard-earned experience. Cheers!

Comment: OP is wrong about the read(0) differences not matting, see which just taught me this https://spectrum-os.org/lists/hyperkitty/list/devel@spectrum-os.org/thread/7UEZD4KF3XZE74S4F7BR2KZL5ZWHTWQ3/

For a UnixDomain datagram socket which is reliable, the buffer can fill up with empty packets, and send/write will block. read(0) means no progress, recv(0) means progress.

Answer (score 105):

Per [the first hit on Google](http://www.developerweb.net/forum/showthread.php?t=2952)

> read() is equivalent to recv() with a flags parameter of 0. Other values for the flags parameter change the behaviour of recv(). Similarly, write() is equivalent to send() with flags == 0.

Comment: This isn't the whole story.  `recv` can only be used on a socket, and will produce an error if you try to use it on, say, `STDIN_FILENO`.

Comment: This thread is now the first hit on Google, Google loves stackoverflow

Comment: @JoeyAdams: On most systems, recv will work just fine on a non-socket (such as STDIN_FILENO).  There are only a few systems on which it will fail (such as windows).

Answer (score 19):

`read()` and `write()` are more generic, they work with any file descriptor.
However, they won't work on Windows.

You can pass additional options to `send()` and `recv()`, so you may have to used them in some cases.

Answer (score 8):

I just noticed recently that when I used `write()` on a socket in Windows, it almost works (the FD passed to `write()` isn't the same as the one passed to `send()`; I used `_open_osfhandle()` to get the FD to pass to `write()`).  However, it didn't work when I tried to send binary data that included character 10.  `write()` somewhere inserted character 13 before this.  Changing it to `send()` with a flags parameter of 0 fixed that problem.  `read()` could have the reverse problem if 13-10 are consecutive in the binary data, but I haven't tested it.  But that appears to be another possible difference between `send()` and `write()`.

Comment: +1. See also [winsock not supporting read/write](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4778043)

Comment: Windows also doesn't receive a UDP packet with less than 3 bytes of data, so, there's issues with Windows. :)

Answer (score 7):

Another thing on linux is:

`send` does not allow to operate on non-socket fd. Thus, for example to write on usb port, `write` is necessary.

Answer (score 5):

On Linux I also notice that :

> **Interruption of system calls and library functions by signal handlers**
>   If a signal handler is invoked while a system call or library function call is blocked, then either:
>
> - the call is automatically restarted after the signal handler returns; or
> - the call fails with the error EINTR.
>
> ... The details vary across UNIX systems; below, the details for Linux.
>
> If  a blocked call to one of the following interfaces is interrupted
>   by a signal handler, then the call is automatically restarted after
>          the signal handler returns if the SA_RESTART flag was used; otherwise the call fails with the error EINTR:
>
> - **read**(2), readv(2), write(2), writev(2), and ioctl(2) calls on "slow" devices.
>
> .....
>
> The  following  interfaces  are  never  restarted after being interrupted by a signal handler, regardless of the use of SA_RESTART; they
>          always fail with the error EINTR when interrupted by a signal handler:
>
> - "Input" socket interfaces, when a timeout  (SO_RCVTIMEO)  has  been  set  on  the  socket  using  setsockopt(2):  accept(2),  **recv**(2),
>          **recvfrom**(2), recvmmsg(2) (also with a non-NULL timeout argument), and recvmsg(2).
> - "Output"  socket  interfaces,  when  a  timeout  (SO_RCVTIMEO)  has  been  set on the socket using setsockopt(2): connect(2), send(2),
>          sendto(2), and sendmsg(2).

Check `man 7 signal` for more details.

---

A simple usage would be use signal to avoid `recvfrom` blocking indefinitely.

An example from *APUE*:

```
#include "apue.h"
#include <netdb.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

#define BUFLEN      128
#define TIMEOUT     20

void
sigalrm(int signo)
{
}

void
print_uptime(int sockfd, struct addrinfo *aip)
{
    int     n;
    char    buf[BUFLEN];

    buf[0] = 0;
    if (sendto(sockfd, buf, 1, 0, aip->ai_addr, aip->ai_addrlen) < 0)
        err_sys("sendto error");
    alarm(TIMEOUT);
    //here
    if ((n = recvfrom(sockfd, buf, BUFLEN, 0, NULL, NULL)) < 0) {
        if (errno != EINTR)
            alarm(0);
        err_sys("recv error");
    }
    alarm(0);
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, n);
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct addrinfo     *ailist, *aip;
    struct addrinfo     hint;
    int                 sockfd, err;
    struct sigaction    sa;

    if (argc != 2)
        err_quit("usage: ruptime hostname");
    sa.sa_handler = sigalrm;
    sa.sa_flags = 0;
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    if (sigaction(SIGALRM, &sa, NULL) < 0)
        err_sys("sigaction error");
    memset(&hint, 0, sizeof(hint));
    hint.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;
    hint.ai_canonname = NULL;
    hint.ai_addr = NULL;
    hint.ai_next = NULL;
    if ((err = getaddrinfo(argv[1], "ruptime", &hint, &ailist)) != 0)
        err_quit("getaddrinfo error: %s", gai_strerror(err));

    for (aip = ailist; aip != NULL; aip = aip->ai_next) {
        if ((sockfd = socket(aip->ai_family, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0) {
            err = errno;
        } else {
            print_uptime(sockfd, aip);
            exit(0);
        }
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "can't contact %s: %s\n", argv[1], strerror(err));
    exit(1);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

"Performance and speed"? Aren't those kind of ... synonyms, here?

Anyway, the `recv()` call takes flags that `read()` doesn't, which makes it more powerful, or at least more convenient. That is one difference. I don't think there is a significant performance difference, but haven't tested for it.

Comment: Perhaps not having to deal with flags may be perceived as more convenient.

Answer (score 1):

*The only difference between recv() and read() is the presence of flags.  With a zero flags argument, recv() is generally equivalent to read()*

Answer (score 0):

you can use write() and read() instead send() and recv() but send() and recv() offer much greater control over your data transmission