# can winsock write to files and sockets using the write call like linux?

Tags: c++, gcc, winsock, msys2

Compiling code in gcc on windows under msys2.

Working code in linux called:

```
write(fd, buf, len)
```

for a file descriptor that wrote to a socket, or a file.

In windows, this code on a socket gives a runtime warning and crashes

```
invalid parameter passed to c runtime function
```

The documentation we found shows using the send call, but I still want to be able to use the same code to either write to a socket or a file. Is this possible under windows?

Comment: Possibly [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12608707/9957598)?

Comment: Note that with MSVC at least you could use _open_osfhandle to convert a socket handle to a C-runtime file descriptor but if you are stuck with just the windows API then WriteFile or the various flavors of send are what you've got.

Comment: `write()` takes a file descriptor. On Linux, sockets are also represented as file descriptors. That is not the case on Windows. So no, on Windows, you cannot use `write()` to write to a socket, you must use `send()`, `WSASend()`, or `WriteFile()`.

Comment: Really cygwin is the best solution. We originally had a problem and went to msys2, but in light of the posix issues, trying to get cygwin working seems like a great solution to avoid this issue