# A signal interrupts the send method in blocking mode

Tags: c, sockets

I'm programming with socket which is in blocking mode, I have a question about `send` method.

In the man page of `send` method, it says:

> [EINTR]            A signal interrupts the system call before any data is transmitted.

It means if a signal interrupts the system call before any data is transmitted, the `send` would return -1 and `errno` would be set to `EINTR`.

My question is that if a part of data has been transmitted when a signal interrupts the system call, what will return. It seems that it shouldn't return -1 because it has send some data. I think it will return the number of data has been transmitted which means `send` method in the blocking mode may return less number of data than you passed as third parameter.

`ssize_t send(int socket, const void *buffer, size_t length, int flags);`

Comment: This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618736/why-is-it-assumed-that-send-may-return-with-less-than-requested-data-transmitted) is similar to my questions and it's more useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answers are pretty clear, but after reading some of your comments, I would like to add some further information.

First of all, you got the idea behind `EINTR` wrong. Getting interrupted by a signal in a syscall is not to be perceived as an error. The rationale behind `EINTR` in slow syscalls (slow syscalls are those that can block forever, like `open(2)` on some file types - terminal devices for example - `accept(2)`, `read(2)` and `write(2)` on some devices - sockets included - etc.) is that if your program was blocked in a syscall and a signal was caught (while still blocked), then it is very likely (but not mandatory) that the signal handler changed state in your program and things are different, so the call returns prematurely with `EINTR` to give you a chance of doing anything that you might want to do. It is not an error like `EINVAL` or `EBADF` or other "real" errors - it's just the way the kernel tells you that a signal was caught.

If you don't want to do anything, then either set the `SA_RESTART` flag on the `sa_flags` field of `struct sigaction` when setting up the signal handler (which causes the syscall to be automatically restarted), or explicitly call `send(2)` again when it returns -1 with `errno` set to `EINTR`.

The bottom line is, there isn't an inherent limitation on the kernel that forces it to return to userspace when signals are caught. Instead, `EINTR` is just a convenient behavior that developers might find useful.

If the kernel was in the midst of transmitting data and a signal was raised, it's no big deal: if data is being transmitted, the syscall is doing progress. The kernel is in process context executing a syscall in behalf of the program that called it, so technically the process is not sleeping anymore. If a signal arrives, it will be pending until the kernel decides that it's time to deliver it to the process - most likely, this happens once `send(2)` returns.

Comment: Thanks for taking the burden of giving a significant amount of background info on this! :-) 1+ btw

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have noticed it for a while and tried to understand it, but I find it's hard to understand unless having some background knowledage about the kernel/signal and so on.

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/send.2.html) is clear.

> **RETURN VALUE**
>
> On success, these calls return the number of bytes sent.  On error, -1 is returned, and errno is set appropriately.
>
> [...]
>
> **EINTR**  A signal occurred before any data was transmitted;

`send()` either returns

- the number of bytes sent
- or `-1`

If `-1` is returned the reason is indicated via the value of `errno`.

If `errno` equals `EINTR` a signal interupted `send()` while **no data had been received** so far.

From this info above one can safely conclude that *if* data had been received the `send()` function would *not* return `-1`, not matter whether a signal was received or not.

Comment: I have the same idea with you but I'm not sure about that. That's because I don't understand why it is an error when "A signal occurred before any data was transmitted", if "a signal occurred" causes the error, why "a signal occurred after some data was transmitted" is a succuss.

Comment: @KudoCC: If you face a different bahaviour, either your program or `send()`'s implementation is buggy.

Comment: @KudoCC: Getting interrupted by a signal is not to be considered an error. At least on Linux you also can switch off this behaviour on a signal base using the signal attribute `SA_RESTART`.

Comment: Thanks, what I want is that you make sure about that :)

Comment: @KudoCC: Isn't this "*From this info above one can safely conclude that ...*" sure enough?

Comment: @KudoCC: You might want to accept this great answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/31160284/694576, but mine.

Comment: Thanks for your advice :D It's generous of you.

Answer (score -1):

> [EINTR] A signal interrupts the system call before any data is transmitted.

This means that if `send()` start transmitting data, it won't be interrupted by any signals. So, transmission will block the receiving of signal until it finishes. The situation that `send()` may return less bytes of data than you passed as third parameter is usually due to the network problems, such as packets lost.

Comment: Do you have some reference to support your answer ? I'm sure that TCP will handle the packets lost without make the `send` method return.

Comment: You can check out how device drivers implement their `write()` functions. `send()` does a lot familiar to `write()` but the network relevant parts. In the implement of `write()`, you will find something like this: `if (signal_pending(current)) return -ERESTARTSYS; ` which will interrupt the transmission if some signals is pending. http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-6-sect-2 maybe can help you.

Comment: Thanks, but we are talking about socket, the implementation seems to be the file system IO, not the network. Though they have the same interface but they are implemented differently.

Comment: socket is a special I/O, the `read()` and `send()` are nearly no different. You can check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1790750/what-is-the-difference-between-read-and-recv-and-between-send-and-write for this. Also, if you actually know the bottom of Linux OS, all of these operations are based on the Virtual Filesystem layer, no matter network socket or files on spin disk.

Comment: Virtual File system offers the same interface to users, but the implementation below is different from each other.

Comment: Of course! `write()` or `send()` are high lever functions based on virtual filesystem not only for userspace, but also parts of kernel space.

Comment: I'm not sure if it will be interrupted by a signal after `send` start to transmitting data, but I think your statement about the returned less bytes is wrong.

Comment: What do feel it wrong with "*... [the] statement about the returned less bytes ...*"?

Comment: I think you need to learn more about kernel. I can explain this in hundreds of words. VFS actually hides the most hardware related details and provides a common interface above. Filipe Gonçalves' answer shows the fact that no matter `write()` or `send()`, before they actually operate datas, they give you a chance to handle the signals which still pending, it is implemented via something like `if (signal_pending(current)) return -ERESTARTSYS;`.

Comment: @alk I thinks it is one of all cases which could cause this. Can you show me some clues about this?

Comment: @DouglasSu I will learn it :) send method in blocking mode returns when a)the peer close the socket b) it finish sending the data c) signal raise . But it won't returns when some packets are lost, tcp will resend them when it receive a repeat ack or timer is time out.

Comment: @alk Actually I have the book. By the way what do you think of this answer ?

Comment: @KudoCC You stand in userspace, I stand at the bottom of OS, So, from your view packets loss can never happen.

Comment: I didn't say packets loss wouldn't happen, but it won't cause `send` method return. But if the receiver never response to the sender, after a period of time, tcp will give up and `send` method will return.

Comment: what will happen if parts of packets are successfully transmitted and they are sent by a single call to send syscall